# Centos server bandwidth

Tags: centos, linux-networking, bandwidth

I have dedicated server with “Basic Unmetered 1 Gbit/sec” bandwidth, I install a centos 7 on it and using Apache, I used it to make a website for sharing video files, My problem is when visitors use all network bandwidth my server be very slow, I want to know is there any limit or anything I can do so the server still alive but with low download speed? or what should I do ?

Comment: Investigate concepts such as “rate limiting” and “traffic shaping”  which can applied by either the Linux kernel and in Apache itself with for instance mod_ratelimit  and/or mod_bw

Comment: I use mod_ratelimit on apache but same problem it get down, I want to limit whole adapter for visitors "800mb/sec" and let "200mb/sec" free for keep server a live and download the player with a low download speed

Comment: Please provide your httpd configuration, especially the rates for mod_ratelimit  and the total number of connections you allow.  mod_ratelimit  by itself is only per HTTP response, and will not respect a total limit for the server.

Comment: My httpd configuration is the original file I did not edit or add anything except (rates for mod_ratelimit) I used this rates for mod_ratelimit ( SetOutputFilter RATE_LIMIT
SetEnv rate-limit 5000 ), I did not know how to set or allow specific total number of connections